# [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to host a discord bot on Heroku.

When it starts I get this error:

```
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided".
```

But here is the weird part. It worked fine when I tested it first in Visual Studio Code. So in the process of me getting the files into Heroku, it got invalid.

Does anyone have a clue of how I can fix this?

Thx for any replies in advance.

Comment: Without seeing how you are handling the token, it would be hard for us to even guess.  Can you post a code sample showing how you get the token and log in with it. (note: do not give us the token, just the code around it, if it's a string directly in the code, replace it with some arbitrary text).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is how I log in with my bot. Where it says TOKEN is where I have mine. I have also tried making TOKEN into a const bot the same happens then. `bot.login('TOKEN', () => {
    console.log;`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a callback, [Client.login](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) doesn't support a callback.  Though in Javascript I would expect an unused parameter to simply be ignored, you should try removing that or convert it to a ``.then`` to handle the Promise that the method does return.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do. I'm pretty new to coding

Comment: You will need to read up on the concepts of Promises then, there are lots of tutorials on the web, here is one but there are many more.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: But how is this supposed to help to fix the error?

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a classroom, the tools here aren't sufficient to teach you Javascript/Node and if you don't know what a promise or a callback are, that is core functionality you need to learn before coming here.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying app on heroku you have to change you `client.login(token)` to `client.login(process.env.token)` and add `token` to [image]
as token - key and value - token copied from discord developers portal, remember **`(important note!)`** letters has to be the same, I mean, if you use capitals in process.env.TOKEN, the config var has to be now TOKEN.

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem, i encrypted the token so that i could store the encrypted token on heroku and decrypt it in the js to pass the actual token to the login method.
The weird part is, if i write the token directly as string into the js file or i use heroku and store it directly there, then it works. But if i store the encrypted token in heroku and decrypt it (and yes it is correctly decrypted) and give the decrypted token to the login method then it does not work.
I dunno if heroku make some weird stuff or discord.js doesnt support something i dont know...

So, what definitly works is:
You insert the token (client secret) on herokus config vars (settings from your dyno), then you use `process.env.BOT_TOKEN` and pass it to your `Discord.Client().login()`.
I assume in your case its `bot.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)`.

So for me it looks like the value i store in heruko and the value i send to discord must be the same...

Answer (score 0):

You should enter a **valid** Discord bot token. You can obtain it by going to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), then "Applications", select your bot, then go to "Bot" and click "Copy" under the token (it says click here to reveal).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this situation.

I discovered that when using **dotenv** to read data from a .env file (Run on my computer), the names are not case sensitive. *(could be wrong)*

> *For example, `TOKEN` will be able to be treated as `token`, meaning when `process.env.token` can be returned with the value of `TOKEN` in the .env
> file*

But when I run on Heroku, what I just said will be gone (`process.env.token` will not return the value of `TOKEN`, but the `token`). Try double-checking that the name matches and correct it.

Comment: Environment variables on Windows are not case sensitive. Pretty much everywhere else, they are.

Answer (score -1):

Like you've said, you logged into your bot with `bot.login('TOKEN', () => { console.log; }`

but bot.login doesn't support callback functions.

What I mean by this is, instead of the code before, you change it to `bot.login('TOKEN')`.